# Adjust for rater when examining agreement or Kappa

Tags: random-effects-model, survey, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am conducting a 10-question survey, with responses of 'yes' and 'no' to each. I want to compare responses to a known 'gold-standard' (also with responses of yes and no). Suppose I have 100 respondents (1000 items).

I can check agreement, Kappa and others if I treat all items equally. However, I'm worried that in this case the respondent is not accounted for, and the result can be skewed by influential respondent ('rater').
How should I approach this?

My goal is not necessarily checking inter-rater agreement, but how respondent 'agree' with the gold standard.

Comment: What do you mean by "treating all items equally?" Do you mean all raters or all questions? Can you just calculate each rater's agreement with the gold standard separately?

Comment: I mean, ignore the fact it's coming from different raters, and compare 200 responses (in case of 20 raters of 10 questions), to 200 'gold-standards'.

Comment: I can calculate separately, but I'm also interested in overall kappa